# optomax digital liquid sensor - python for raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, liquid, sensors

I've found arduino code for this adafruit digital liquid sensor here

```
    // Liquid level detection using an SST sensor
    // When a liquid touches the tip of the sensor,
    // an LED at pin 13 turns on.
    
    // Pins
    const int LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN = 7;
    const int LED_PIN = 13;
    
    void setup() { 
      pinMode(LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);
      pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
    
    void loop() {
    
      // Read sensor. If liquid touches the tip, the sensor will 
      // read 0V. Turn on LED if liquid is present.
      int isDry = digitalRead(LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN);
      if ( isDry ) {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
      } else {
        digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
      }
    
      delay(200);
    }
```

but nothing written in python for the raspberry pi - (i'm not bothered about triggering an led just the syntax) - has anyone done it ?

Comment: what you would need to do is find the "driver" code to see what pins do what. then you would set the gpio pins using the python pakage

Comment: Ah, let me see.  The Arduino C++ statement to read the sensor is the following: "***int isDry = digitalRead(LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN);***" You might like us to read your Rpi code doing similar things. If your sensor is capacitive. The following Q&A might help: "***Capacitive humidity sensor principle of operation***:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522956/capacitive-moisture-sensor-not-quite-working/523162#523162. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins to read digital sensors. To do this in Python, I recommend that you check out the [WiringPi-Python project](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python#quick-install).

First you need to install the library.

```sh
pip install wiringpi
```

Then you could use the following (untested) code to read the sensor and display the results on the LED:

```py
import wiringpi
import time

LOW = 0
HIGH = 1
LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN = 23
LED_PIN = 24

wiringpi.wiringPiSetupGpio()

wiringpi.pinMode(LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN, wiringpi.GPIO.INPUT)
wiringpi.pinMode(LED_PIN, wiringpi.GPIO.OUTPUT)
wiringpi.digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW)

while True:
    pin_state = wiringpi.digitalRead(LIQUID_SENSOR_PIN)
    is_dry = (pin_state == 0)

    if is_dry:
        wiringpi.digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW)
    else:
        wiringpi.digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH)

    time.sleep(0.2)
```